# Is there a technical reason why it would be better for the COM DLL to delete the passed in temporary JSON when it is finished with it?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, com, delete-file

### Context

1. My parent MFC project creates a JSON file:

   ```
   CImportFromCLMExplorerDlg::CreateMSATranslationsJson(strTempJson);
   ```
2. This temporary file is passed into a C# COM DLL as a parameter for it to use:

   ```
   theApp.MSAToolsInterface().ImportHistoryFromCLMExplorer(
                        theApp.GetLanguageCode(dlgImportCLM.GetLanguageToImport()),
                        dlgImportCLM.GetCalendarDBPath(),
                        theApp.GetAssignHistoryXMLPath(),
                        strTempJson);
   ```
3. Finally, I delete the temporary file after the above COM DLL method returns:

   ```
   ::DeleteFile(strTempJson);
   ```

### My question

It is technically a better approach to get the COM DLL to delete this file once it has finished using it? Or is it perfectly fine (it appears to be) to delete it after in the parent project?

I am not asking for opinions but asking if there is technical reason why it would be better for the COM DLL to delete the passed in temporary JSON when it is finished with it.

### The JSON File

The comments allude to the possibility of using an `ISteam` and not passing a literal file. At the moment I am creating the JSON file like this:

```
bool CImportFromCLMExplorerDlg::CreateMSATranslationsJson(const CString strPathJson)
{
    CkString strOut, strValue;
    CkJsonObject json;
    bool success;

    LanguageMSA eLang = theApp.GetProgramLanguage();

    // Note: The methods return false if "out of memory"

    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_BIBLE_READING));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReading", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_BIBLE_READING_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReadingMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_BIBLE_READING_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReadingAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_INITIAL_CALL));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCall", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_INITIAL_CALL_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_INITIAL_CALL_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_RETURN_VISIT));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisit", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_RETURN_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_RETURN_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_BIBLE_STUDY));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudy", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_STUDY_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudyMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_STUDY_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudyAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_TALK));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Talk", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_TALK_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "TalkMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_TALK_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "TalkAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_ASSISTANT));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Assistant", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_QA));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "QuestionsAndAnswers", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_DISC_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "DiscussionWithVideo", strValue);
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "SampleConversation", "Sample Conversation");
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_INITIAL_CALL_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallVideo", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_RETURN_VISIT_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitVideo", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Video", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_THEME_PRESENTATIONS));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Presentations", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_THEME_SPIRITUAL_GEMS));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "SpiritualGems", strValue);


    json.put_EmitCompact(false);
    strOut.append(json.emit());
    strOut.append("\r\n");
    
    CkString strPathJsonEx;
    strPathJsonEx.setStringU(strPathJson);
    return strOut.saveToFile(strPathJsonEx, "utf-8");
}
```

It uses the [`CkJsonObject`](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkJsonObjectRef.html) and [`CkString`](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkStringRef.html#method138) classes. I am not sure if it is possible to turn that into an object that can be passed to the DLL. For the record this is how I read in the JSON in the COM DLL at the moment:

```
private MSATranslations GetMSATranslations(string strPath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(strPath, Encoding.UTF8))
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MSATranslations>(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: A far better solution wouldn't create a temporary file at all. COM provides the [`IStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) interface for that purpose. You can create an `IStream` over a filesystem object, or memory. None of the code that reads from it needs to know, where the data comes from. You can pass it around freely, and don't have to care about cleanup. Once the final reference is dropped, the memory is released (or the file is closed).

Comment: @IInspectable An interesting idea. I am using `CkJsonObject` (see: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkJsonObjectRef.html) to create the json data in my MFC project. I am not sure how to pass that object as this `IStream`. I'll update the question with the function content.

Comment: Instead of taking the result of `emit()` and writing it to a file, write it to memory and pass that memory.

Comment: @RaymondChen Looking at the available documents it is not clear to me how to get from the `CkString` and putting it into this `IStream` to pass it to the COM DLL.

Comment: The IStream was just one way to pass the data in memory rather than via a file. Passing as a string also works.

Comment: @RaymondChen So your suggesting that I simply pass the whole JSON as ` CComBSTR` to my DLL and it will be able to parse that instead into the JSON.

Comment: Since you are using a `StreamReader` in the C# code, passing an `IStream` in place of a filename is the least intrusive (you would only have to use a different [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-io-stream))). You can construct a stream using [`SHCreateMemStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) or [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-createstreamonhglobal).

Comment: @RaymondChen for the string approach, it looks like `c#` will be able to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MSATranslations>(strJsonContent)`.

Comment: You could also provide your own `IStream` implementation that takes a `CkString`, if you want to prevent memory allocations and copies, though I wouldn't worry about this. The data appears to be small (a few kilobytes at most).

Comment: @IInspectable I think initially I will try to pass the JSON as a string and just deseerialize that. See if it works.

Comment: If you can deserialize from a string then passing a `BSTR` is fine as well. Just make sure to use UTF-16 encoding. `CkString` appears to support UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: @IInspectable It is working! Passing the unicode string. Awesome. I notice you mention `BSTR` but what i tend to do with my MFC wrapper (which is passed a `CString`) I then convert it: `CComBSTR bstrTranslationsJson(strTranslationsJson);` and pass that value into the DLL method. I have not used `BSTR`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I put an answer together.

Comment: @IInspectable I added my own answer based on the changes I made. I could grasp passing a string easier than the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1

```
Adjust the code that creates the JSON to simply build a `CString`:

bool CImportFromCLMExplorerDlg::CreateMSATranslationsJson(CString &strTranslationsJson)
{
    CkString strOut, strValue;
    CkJsonObject json;
    bool success;

    LanguageMSA eLang = theApp.GetProgramLanguage();

    // Note: The methods return false if "out of memory"

    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_BIBLE_READING));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReading", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_BIBLE_READING_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReadingMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_BIBLE_READING_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleReadingAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_INITIAL_CALL));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCall", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_INITIAL_CALL_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_INITIAL_CALL_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_RETURN_VISIT));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisit", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_RETURN_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_RETURN_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_BIBLE_STUDY));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudy", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_STUDY_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudyMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_STUDY_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "BibleStudyAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_TALK));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Talk", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_TALK_MAIN));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "TalkMain", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_TALK_AUX));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "TalkAux", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_HISTORY_ASSISTANT));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Assistant", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_QA));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "QuestionsAndAnswers", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_DISC_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "DiscussionWithVideo", strValue);
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "SampleConversation", "Sample Conversation");
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_INITIAL_CALL_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "InitialCallVideo", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_RETURN_VISIT_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "ReturnVisitVideo", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_CMB_METHOD_VIDEO));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Video", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_THEME_PRESENTATIONS));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "Presentations", strValue);
    strValue.setStringU(SMMETHOD3(eLang, IDS_STR_THEME_SPIRITUAL_GEMS));
    success = json.AddStringAt(-1, "SpiritualGems", strValue);

    json.put_EmitCompact(false);
    strOut.append(json.emit());
    strOut.append("\r\n");

    strTranslationsJson = strOut.getUnicode();

    return true;
}
```

### Step 2

Pass **that** string to the API COM wrapper:

```
CString strTranslationsJson;
if (CImportFromCLMExplorerDlg::CreateMSATranslationsJson(strTranslationsJson))
{
    theApp.MSAToolsInterface().ImportHistoryFromCLMExplorer(
        theApp.GetLanguageCode(dlgImportCLM.GetLanguageToImport()),
        dlgImportCLM.GetCalendarDBPath(),
        theApp.GetAssignHistoryXMLPath(),
        strTranslationsJson);
}
```

### Step 3

The wrapper passes it as a `CComBSTR` to the DLL:

```
void CMSATools::ImportHistoryFromCLMExplorer(const CString strLanguageCode, const CString strCalendarDBPath, const CString strHistoryDBPath, const CString strTranslationsJson)
{
    if (m_pInterface != nullptr)
    {
        CComBSTR bstrLanguageCode(strLanguageCode);
        CComBSTR bstrCalendarDBPath(strCalendarDBPath);
        CComBSTR bstrHistoryDBPath(strHistoryDBPath);
        CComBSTR bstrTranslationsJson(strTranslationsJson);
        m_pInterface->ImportHistoryFromCLMExplorer(bstrLanguageCode,
            bstrCalendarDBPath, bstrHistoryDBPath, bstrTranslationsJson);
    }
}
```

### Step 4

Finally, in the DLL we turn that string into our required object:

```
private MSATranslations GetMSATranslations(string strTranslationsJson)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MSATranslations>(strTranslationsJson);
}
```

It works very well. No physical JSON file any more!