# Is it acceptable to pass this amount of JSON information as a parameter to a C# COM DLL method?

Tags: json, com

This question is an extension to this one ([Is there a technical reason why it would be better for the COM DLL to delete the passed in temporary JSON when it is finished with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70658194/2287576)) where it was suggested I pass JSON content as a `BSTR` to my C# COM DLL.

Here is an example of the type of data being passed:

```
{
  "BibleReading": "Bible Reading",
  "BibleReadingMain": "Bible Reading (Main)",
  "BibleReadingAux": "Bible Reading (Aux)",
  "InitialCall": "Initial Call",
  "InitialCallMain": "Initial Call (Main)",
  "InitialCallAux": "Initial Call (Aux)",
  "ReturnVisit": "Return Visit",
  "ReturnVisitMain": "Return Visit (Main)",
  "ReturnVisitAux": "Return Visit (Aux)",
  "BibleStudy": "Bible Study",
  "BibleStudyMain": "Bible Study (Main)",
  "BibleStudyAux": "Bible Study (Aux)",
  "Talk": "Talk",
  "TalkMain": "Talk (Main)",
  "TalkAux": "Talk (Aux)",
  "Assistant": "Assistant",
  "QuestionsAndAnswers": "Questions and Answers",
  "DiscussionWithVideo": "Discussion with Video",
  "SampleConversation": "Sample Conversation",
  "InitialCallVideo": "Initial Call Video",
  "ReturnVisitVideo": "Return Visit Video",
  "Video": "Video",
  "Presentations": "Prepare This Month’s Presentations",
  "SpiritualGems": "Spiritual Gems",
}
```

I want to extent this JSON to include 15 more items:

```
{
  "BibleReading": "Bible Reading",
  "BibleReadingMain": "Bible Reading (Main)",
  "BibleReadingAux": "Bible Reading (Aux)",
  "InitialCall": "Initial Call",
  "InitialCallMain": "Initial Call (Main)",
  "InitialCallAux": "Initial Call (Aux)",
  "ReturnVisit": "Return Visit",
  "ReturnVisitMain": "Return Visit (Main)",
  "ReturnVisitAux": "Return Visit (Aux)",
  "BibleStudy": "Bible Study",
  "BibleStudyMain": "Bible Study (Main)",
  "BibleStudyAux": "Bible Study (Aux)",
  "Talk": "Talk",
  "TalkMain": "Talk (Main)",
  "TalkAux": "Talk (Aux)",
  "Assistant": "Assistant",
  "QuestionsAndAnswers": "Questions and Answers",
  "DiscussionWithVideo": "Discussion with Video",
  "SampleConversation": "Sample Conversation",
  "InitialCallVideo": "Initial Call Video",
  "ReturnVisitVideo": "Return Visit Video",
  "Video": "Video",
  "Presentations": "Prepare This Month’s Presentations",
  "SpiritualGems": "Spiritual Gems",
  "Discuss": "Discussion",
  "DiscussDemos": "Discussion with Demonstration(s)",
  "DiscussDemosInterviews": "Discussion with Demonstration(s) and Interview(s)",
  "DiscussInterviews": "Discussion with Interview(s)",
  "DiscussVideo": "Discussion with Video",
  "DiscussVideos": "Discussion with Videos",
  "QuestionAnswer": "Questions and Answers",
  "QuestionAnswerDemos": "Questions and Answers with Demonstration(s)",
  "QuestionAnswerDemosInterviews": "Questions and Answers with Demonstration(s) and Interview(s)",
  "QuestionAnswerInterviews": "Questions and Answers with Interview(s)",
  "TalkDemos": "Talk with Demonstration(s)",
  "TalkDemosInterviews": "Talk with Demonstration(s) and Interview(s)",
  "TalkInterviews": "Talk with Interview(s)",
  "TalkVideo": "Talk with Video",
  "TalkVideos": "Talk with Videos"
}
```

Is it still going to be acceptable to pass this amount of information as a `BSTR` to my COM API method? I assume there is some kind of limit as to how much data can be passed.

Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The BSTR theoretical limit in bytes is UINT max value (4G). Obviously, you'll never get to this. BSTR usually store unicode characters. Your text is ~2619 characters which will require (~2619+1 * 2) + 4 bytes ((characters + terminating zero) * 2 + size len) = ~5244 bytes. There's absolutely no issue using the text you show.

Comment: @SimonMourier Great thanks for confirming that. It is unicode text because it also supports passing the values in other languages, like Japanese or Russian etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write a test program if you don't know the answer. Here's one that verifies 1 megabyte `BSTR` which is way more than your example. You could change the amount allocated to whatever you want. At some point it will break.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    const size_t MEGABYTEPLUSONE = 1024 * 1024 + 1;
    auto pChar = std::make_unique<OLECHAR[]>(MEGABYTEPLUSONE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MEGABYTEPLUSONE - 2; ++i)
        pChar[i] = (i % 26) + 65;

    pChar[MEGABYTEPLUSONE - 1] = 0;
    
    _bstr_t bstr(pChar.get());
    int len = bstr.length();
    wcout << L"Length of BSTR: " << len << endl;
    const WCHAR* const pwcStart = bstr.GetBSTR();
    for (const WCHAR* pwc = pwcStart;  pwc < pwcStart + 52; ++pwc)
        wcout << *pwc;
    wcout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```